# How to collapse only children in OrgChart?

Tags: jquery, orgchart, organizational-chart

I found this awesome library for creating organizational charts called [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart).

Here it is what it looks like:
[image]

The green arrows allow you to collapse the parents/children/siblings nodes. You can try it here to see what I mean: [example](https://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/toggle-sibs-resp.html)

My goal is to remove all the green arrows except the children ones so that I can collapse only vertically starting from the very top of the organization. Do you have any idea how I can reach such result please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

In the file [jquery.orgchart.js](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.orgchart.js) you need to remove from all the  tags the following items:

- `class="edge horizontalEdge rightEdge oci"`
- `class="edge horizontalEdge leftEdge oci"`
- `class="edge verticalEdge topEdge oci"`

So that you are only left with `<i class="edge verticalEdge bottomEdge oci"></i>` and all the other tags are `<i></i>`

[image]